# Installing on IIS 7/Windows Server 2008 R2/MSSQL 2008

Tags: 8, iis

I am having difficulty connecting to my MSSQL database (locally installed) while proceeding through the Drupal Install. I do not get any errors during the Verify Requirements portion, but not matter what info I put into the Database configuration page, it cannot connect. It does not throw an error like "phpmssql library missing"

This is what I have installed so far.

- Windows 2008 Server R2
- Internet Information Server IIS 7.5
- SQL Server 10.0
- Microsoft Drivers for PHP for SQL Server 3.2
- php-5.6.21-nts-Win32-VC11-x86
- php_pdo_sql_srv_56_nts.dll
- php_wincache-1.3.7.9-5.6-nts-vc11-x86
- sqlsrv-8.x-1.x-dev
- wincachedrupal-7.x-1.10

Should I be putting something besides "localhost" and "1433" in the "Advanced Options" panel?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score -1):

> phpmssql library missing

You are using the 8.x-2.x branch of the driver, that relies on a paid external library phpmssl:

http://www.drupalonwindows.com/en/content/phpmssql

You can use the "free" 8.x-1.x branch - that has no dependencies - for evaluation purposes. I say evaluation because it's a non supported half-broken branch I used to work on during the first D8 port attempt of the driver.

You can find full discussiones of this issue here:

http://www.drupalonwindows.com/en/blog/installing-drupal-8-windows

Disclaimer: I'm the maintainer for the SQL Server driver, PHP Mssql and Wincache.

Comment: David,

I've visited your site before, that's why I am using the sqlsrv-8.x-1.x-dev branch, due to it not having any dependencies. I stated 'It does not throw an error like "phpmssql library missing".', so my problem lies somewhere else.

Comment: Ok, I did not read that properly. Then you should share what error it is throwing....